# algorithm: return the sub graph with max sum

Tags: graph

given a connected graph, each node has an integer (positive or negative),  how to find out the sub-graph whose sum of the node value is the maximum value?

in a simplified case,  if this graph is a linear linked list, then the question become "return the sub-array in a 1-dimension array, where the sum of the sub-array is the biggest".  we know there exists an O(n) soluiton.

to make my question simpler,  let's assume each node cannot have more than 4 edges.

I had looked at some graph algorithms, but haven't found the exact solution.

Comment: can you show your work please?

Comment: Is your problem possibly restricted to planar graphs?

Comment: yes, the edges don't cross each other, beside being connected at the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put no restrictions on the structure of the subgraph, just delete the nodes with negative values.  This always results in the subgraph with max node sum.

Comment: The question is ill-posed so I think this is a fair answer. However, if a negative node is a bridge (in the graph-theoretic sense), then it would split the graph into two separately connected components. I'm guessing that this is not what the OP wants, but it's hard to tell for sure.